# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Active' of undefined

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, typescript

I've got an account page in my SPA that i'm currently trying to populate with information from my database.

I've used Postman to see that the property I am trying to access is available. As well as I'm able to access another property from the same element.

JSON from Postman

```
{
    "newsSubscription": {
        "SubscriptionID": "1",
        "ObjectID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "OrganizationNumber": null,
        "CompanyName": null,
        "Active": true,
        "SubscriptionType": 1,
        "ObjectType": 1
    },
    "Subscriptions": [],
    "Email": "email@email.com"
}
```

I'm accessing the API using axios. I'm able to get the email address, but can't seem to access the true/false of "Active", which will determine if the checkbox is checked or not.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    state = {
        emailAddress: [],
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(
            'http://api',
            { withCredentials: true }
        )
        .then(res => {
            const emailAddress = res.data;
            this.setState({ emailAddress });
        })
        //error handling
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // Removed for simplicity
            <Typography>The registered e-mail address for your account is <b>{this.state.emailAddress.Email}</b></Typography>
            <Checkbox
                checked={this.state.emailAddress.newsSubscription.Active}
                value="email_notifications"
                color="primary"
            />
        );
    }
}
```

I would like the API property "Active" to check or uncheck the checkbox based on a true/false response from the API call.

Comment: I think the reason is that your `render` function is trying to access the value even before the axios request is resolved.

Comment: @vipulp, is there a way to make sure this doesn't happen?

Comment: One way would be to put a condition before rendering so that it only accesses it when its loaded.

 `{this.state.emailAddress.length > 0 && 
                <Typography>The registered e-mail address for your account is <b> 
                  {this.state.emailAddress.Email}</b></Typography>
                    <Checkbox
                        checked={this.state.emailAddress.newsSubscription.Active}
                        value="email_notifications"
                        color="primary"
                    />}`

Answer (score 0):

Please add in the render section

```
console.log(this.state.emailAddress);
```

to see what is coming. Maybe there is an issue on how the data is arriving and that is why it fails.

Comment: So, if i have the this.state.emailAddress.newsSubscription.Active, then the console writes a blank array. If i remove this.state.emailAddress.newsSubscription.Active, and still keep the this.state.emailAddress.Email, then the console writes out the JSON as I retrieve in Postman

Answer (score 0):

```js
    state = {
        emailAddress: [],
    }
```

Your state is quite confusing. Your `state.emailAddress` semms to be an array, but you use it like an object: `this.state.emailAddress.newsSubscription`.

Your API give you an object, or an array ? I think your issue is here.

Comment: You're right, when i check ```console.log(this.state.emailAddress);```, then I see that its returned as an object. How would I go about printing this out, only worked with Arrays before.